# ASP.net DataGrid adding extra information to table I do not want

Tags: asp.net

Here is what DataGrid does to my table:

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_articleList" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;" headertext="File Name" rules="all">
```

How can I remove the unnecessary info from the table?

I do not want cellSpacing, anything in the style.  I take care of all of thise with CSS and because these are inline it is overriding my CSS declarations.

I don't care if the ID, or rules="all" (not even sure what that does) or the HeaderText is present, but I would love to get rid of the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Curt suggested, you can use a `Repeater` control for more control over the output. Another option would be the `ListView` control, which gives you more options than the the `Repeater` does.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="myclass">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("ColumnName", "{0:#,###} bytes") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Just looked up the additional things i can do with listview and have to say i like this solution much better.  Thank again.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want full control over your table, I would recommend using a [Repeater](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp) instead. Unlike the `DataGrid` control, the `Repeater` control doesn't render any HTML which isn't inside the `ItemTemplate` giving you full control over your rendered code.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column Header</td>
  </tr>
  <asp:repeater id="rep" runat="server">
    <itemtemplate>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <%#eval("ColumnName") %>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </asp:repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: this seems to work very nicely.  I do have one questions, in my DataGrid I am able to DataFormatString="{0:#,### bytes}" to display 3,546 bytes.  Is this possible with the repeater?

Comment: @JamesWilson: Yes, you can do that in the `Eval` function: `Eval("ColumnName", "{0:#,### bytes}")`

Comment: @JamesJohnson Your are a scholar and a gentleman, thank you!  Great name by the way. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> As the the Eval/DataItem will give object/String return value. In
>   order to convert into 3,546 bytes output, it is required to convert it into
>   integer. For that `onitemdatabound` event registration will be required.

### Mark Up

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rpt_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="myclass">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" ></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

---

### Code Behind

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Label lbl= (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl");
        lbl.Text = String.Format("{0:#,### bytes}", 
              Convert.ToInt32(((YourClassName)e.Item.DataItem).YourProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hrm, I didn't add any of this and it converted it to the correct format from James's suggestion.  Is it possible not adding the items you mentioned could cause errors down the road for me?

Comment: i tried at my end, it started to work as mention in my post. if it is already working ur side. then it's fine.

Comment: @JamesWilson: I wouldn't expect any problems using formatting options provided through the `Eval` function. This example is doing essentially the same thing, just with a little more work required in the code-behind.

Comment: @PankajGarg: You you don't need to convert the value to an integer like that, since `string.Format` will accept type `object` as an argument and apply the format to it. In the code-behind, it would also be easier to just use `DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ColumnName", "{0:#,### bytes}")`